# Need help with uniform continuity

Tags: uniform-continuity

I came across this problem which I can't solve, suppose we have $f(x) = x\sqrt{(1+x)/(1-x)}$ , is it uniform continuous in $[-1, 1)$, $[-1, 0)$, and $[0, 1)$ , what I've seen in most places that does the trick is somehow starting from $|f(x_1)-f(x_2)|$ to get something that has $|x_1-x_2|$ in it and it all works out from there on but I can't seem to pull it off here. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: In general, for differentiable functions, you only need that the derivative is bounded in the region, because of the mean value theorem.

Comment: But if a function is not bounded in a bounded region, then it is not uniformly continuous, so that should answer at least one part.

Answer (score 0):

The mathmetical definition of a function being uniformly continuos is that for every $\mu$ > 0, there exists $\beta$ > 0, such that for every x,x' belonging to $I$, if  |x-x'|<$\beta$ $\implies$ |$f$(x)-$f$(x')|< $\mu$! You shall search for $\beta$ satisfying the implication! $I$ being the domain!

Comment: Don't mix up all those dollar signs. Just write `$|x-x'|<\beta\implies ...$`.

Comment: Im new sorry :/!

Comment: Yeah, just trying to help. You should be able to do everything mathematical inside `$`s.

Comment: Well thankyouuu!